# use asp.net web api token to authenticate my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, access-token, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a new web api project with individual user account authentication.

I followed this post and everything worked as expected

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Now, I have a token end point 
    localhost:54452/Token

Lets, say I create new asp.net mvc application. I want to use this token end point for authentication. How do I tell my controllers to use this token end point? How do I tell my controllers to pass the bearer access token on each request or how does these two work together.

asp.net mvc and asp.net web api are two different projects with different port numbers

Thanks,

Syed

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper class that uses HttpClient to issue HTTP requests to the Web API. Then use this wrapper class when you're communicating with the Web API. It will then handle adding the token to the HTTP request header.